# pip install package call setup.py install instead of setup.py bdist_wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have create a private package and simply all things are well. `setup.py bdist_wheel` simply create the wheel for it and other commands works correct.

also `pip install package_xxx.whl` works fine and installs the created wheel correctly. but when I try to `pip install` the package from a requirement file or git repo or local path, it sucks...

As you know the pip will call setup.py file

In my case the `setup.py` file called twice with following arguments:  (captured from sys.argv)

```
['-c', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', 'pip-egg-info']
['-c', 'install', '--record', '/long/path/to/install-record.txt', '--single-version-externally-managed', '--compile']
```

but for example if I `pip install coverage` the setup.py file of coverage package called twice with following:

```
['-c', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', 'pip-egg-info']
['-c', 'bdist_wheel', '-d', '/long/path/to/tmp82jyoapip-wheel-', '--python-tag', 'cp27']
```

the first call to `setup.py` in my package and the coverage.py package is same and pip gets the egg-info data. then it call `setup.py bdist_wheel` on coverage.py **(the desired behavior)** but call `setup.py install` on my package **(broken behavior)** that lead to create egg-like project not wheel one.

my setup.py file is in following gist: https://gist.github.com/wtayyeb/f26578fe6ff17dc6acd3

it is beside other files in the package and as I say all things are working except `pip install /path/to/mypackage`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in folder name that containes setup.py. I have found it with inspecting `pip` and found the critical check which was direct the process to legacy method. see below link if you intrest in it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590238/875667