# How pip recognize to create wheel for a package

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

How `pip` decide to run `setup.py bdist_wheel` againest legacy `setup.py install` on a package?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is described somewhere! but I dont know exacly where. maybe in one PEP.

The main check of whether to create a wheel or not is in https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/wheel.py#L773

the `pip.index.egg_info_matches` checks basename of your package with `r'([a-z0-9_.]+)-([a-z0-9_.!+-]+)'`. That means `setup.py` containing folder name must be in form of `mypackage-anything` in first place! otherwise the above check will fail and the legacy installation will starts.

Comment: The link won't work. Please provide permalink when possible.