# How to force pip install --editable to create wheel cache instead of egg?

Tags: python, pip, installation, python-wheel, egg

When I do the following, with verbose flag,

`pip install -e file:////path/to/setupdir`

I see that it is running `setup.py develop` underneath and ends up creating .egg instead of .whl

How to force pip creation of wheel instead?

PS: I know that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589293/how-pip-recognize-to-create-wheel-for-a-package/35590238) is on this topic, but the answer is unsatisfactory (debatable), the link in answer is broken and does not talk about --editable mode

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I would also like to know as my setup.py seems to be creating an egg and I don't know how to force it to create a wheel. BTW: they still haven't fixed the broken link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The editable installation mode of pip seems to make use of the special [`.egg-link` format of eggs](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/docs/deprecated/python_eggs.rst#egg-links), so there is probably no simple way to install a python package as a wheel in editable mode.

Editable installs are equivalent to the development mode of setuptools,  in this mode, the files are actually not copied to the deployment directory, instead, only a `.egg-link` file is created in the deployment directory. The `.egg-link` file contains the path where to find the code of your package. Next to the source code of your package, a `.egg-info` directory is created to store some metadata. You can find more information about pip editable installs and the setuptools development mode in these pages of the documentations of [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) and [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html).

When using the editable installation mode, we can see in the pip source code [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7369ac2ee85815d4a059c667cc415f2000df7ed5/src/pip/_internal/wheel_builder.py#L68) that no wheel is built.

The python package [editables](https://pypi.org/project/editables/) seems to provide this option.